# Postgres: How to efficiently bucketize random event ids below (hour,config_id,sensor_id)

Tags: postgresql

I have a large table "measurement" with 4 columns:

```
measurement-service=> \d measurement
                                Table "public.measurement"
        Column         |            Type             | Collation | Nullable | Default 
-----------------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 hour                  | timestamp without time zone |           | not null | 
 config_id             | bigint                      |           | not null | 
 sensor_id             | bigint                      |           | not null | 
 event_id              | uuid                        |           | not null | 
Partition key: RANGE (hour)
Indexes:
    "hour_config_id_sensor_id_event_id_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (hour, config_id, sensor_id, event_id)
Number of partitions: 137 (Use \d+ to list them.)
```

An example of a partition name: "measurement_y2019m12d04"

And then i insert a lot of events as CSV via COPY to a temporary table, and from there i copy the table directly into the partition using ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING.

Example:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE 'tmp_measurement_y2019m12d04T02_12345' (
  hour timestamp without timezone,
  config_id bigint,
  sensor_id bigint,
  event_id uuid
) ON COMMIT DROP;
[...]
COPY tmp_measurement_y2019m12d04T02_12345 FROM STDIN DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
INSERT INTO measurement_y2019m12d04 (SELECT * FROM tmp_measurement_y2019m12d04T02_12345) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```

I think i help postgres by sending CSV with data of the same hour only. Also within that hour, i remove all duplicates in the CSV. Therefore the CSV only contains unique rows.

But i send many batches for different hours. There is no order. It can be the hour of today, yesterday, the last week. Etc.

My approach worked alright so far, but i think i have reached a limit now. The insertion speed has become very slow. While the CPU is idle, i have 25% i/o wait. Subsystem is a RAID with several TB, using disks, that are not SSD.

```
maintenance_work_mem = 32GB
max_wal_size = 1GB
fsync = off
max_worker_processes = 256
wal_buffers = -1
shared_buffers = 64GB
temp_buffers = 4GB
effective_io_concurrency = 1000
effective_cache_size = 128GB
```

Each partition per day is around 20gb big and contains no more than 500m rows. And by maintaining the unique index per partition, i just duplicated the data once more.

The lookup speed, on the other hand, is quick.

I think the limit is in the maintenance of the btree with the rather random UUIDs in (hour,config_id,sensor_id). I constantly change it, its written out and has to be re-read.

I am wondering, if there is another approach. Basically i want uniqueness for (hour,config_id,sensor_id,event_id) and then a quick lookup per (hour,config_id,sensor_id).

I am considering removal of the unique index and only having an index over (hour,config_id,sensor_id). And then providing the uniqueness on the reader side. But it may slow down the reading, as the event_id can no longer be delivered via the index, when i lookup via (hour,config_id,sensor_id). It has to access the actual row to get the event_id.

Or i provide uniqueness via a hash index.

Any other ideas are welcome!

Thank you.

Comment: "But i send many batches for different hours. There is no order. It can be the hour of today, yesterday, the last week. Etc." But you only show one temp table. Do you make multiple passes over the raw data for different days? Or are you populating multiple temp tables simultaneously?

Comment: Being the last column in the index, the randomness of the uuid is unlikely to be very important.  How many different event_id are there for the same combination of (hour, config_id, sensor_id) in any given load?

Comment: Yes, i populate multiple temp tables simultaneously. And it can be hundreds or thousands of different ids per (hour, config_id, sensor_id).

Why do you think, the event_id might not be very important? It still has to be sorted into the index.

Comment: Once it is sorted on the three preceding fields that should reduced the size of the "working set" on the last field to the point it will be well-cached even if not sorted.  Unless each combination of first three field can still have millions of uuid in any given load.

Comment: Do you need a unique constraint at all?  If you deduplicate within the hour on the client side, and hour is part of the unique index, so things with different hours can't be duplicates by definition, then how would duplicates arise?  Is your deduplication within the hour purely a "best effort" and not guaranteed to be effective?

Comment: Yes, it is "best effort". I may get the same event_id for the same (hour,config_id,sensor_id) also later. For example, mostly it is realtime insertion, i get sensor data, i group by (hour,config_id,sensor_id) and then i insert in parallel per seen hour. But if the realtime pipeline fails, i have to re-import via batch process. And in that moment it is very convenient to rely "ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING".

Comment: Sadly, I have no numbers about how many duplicates per (hour,config_id,sensor_id) i can expect. Maybe i should just try it out. But probably by avoiding the unique index i save half the disk space also. Hm hm.

Comment: Try to increase the `max_wal_size` option for 2 or even 4 times. Lets say: PostgreSQL have 64 GB of shared buffers but it should to write to disk each 1 GB of changes. Increasing this parameter could to decrease the amount of disk operations.

Comment: PS: More in this great blogpost: https://evol-monkey.blogspot.com/2019/10/tuning-checkpoints.html

Answer (score 0):

When you do the insert, you should specify an ORDER BY which matches the index of the table being inserted into:

```
INSERT INTO measurement_y2019m12d04 
    SELECT * FROM tmp_measurement_y2019m12d04T02_12345 
        order by hour, config_id, sensor_id, event_id
```

Only if this fails to give enough improvement would I consider any of the other options you list.

Hash indexes don't provide uniqueness.  You can simulate it with an exclusion constraint, but I think they are less efficient.  Exclusion constraints do support DO NOTHING, but not support DO UPDATE. So as long as your use case does not evolve to want DO UPDATE, you would be good on that front, but I still doubt it would actually solve the problem.  If your bottleneck is IO from updating the index, hash would only make it worse as it is designed to scatter your data all over the place, rather than focus it in a small cacheable area.

You also mention parallel processing.  For inserting into the temp table, that might be fine.  But I wouldn't do the INSERT...SELECT in parallel.  If IO is your bottleneck, that would probably just make it worse.  Of course if IO is no longer the bottleneck after my ORDER BY suggestion, then ignore this part.